# Draw mathematical functions in Java using JFreeChart

Tags: java, math, plot, jfreechart

I've been googling my for a while now, and did not find any useful stuff, so that is why I ask you guys.

Can I draw mathematical functions (e.g. sine, cosine, etc.) with JFreeChart?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I believe that you can do this. What does the JFreeChart documentation tell you about this?

Comment: Yes you can - not sure if it is built in but you just need to create an XY series (with y = cos(x) for example) and draw it. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well, not much. This is my problem in fact: I did not find any helpful stuff in the reference.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to create a graph of some mathematical functions. But this XY series seems to help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JFreeChart is for plotting data, not functions. But you should be able to create a table of (x,y) values and then plot them. If this is for a desktop app, look at the JavaFX api. The API includes charts and functions to draw lines.

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming that you can plot the points yourself in which case you would simply evaluate the mathematical function for each x along the graph.

```
getY(float x) {
    return /*your function*/ Math.sin(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There may not be a built in way to plot sinx but there doesn't need to be. Remember that what your saying is y=sin(x)! What you need to plot is the x and y value. Create a loop of x values then plug them into sin(x) using Java and Math. That answer IS your y value! So now you have your x and y values to plot sin(x).

Example

```
final XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("First");


    for(double i = 0; i < 10; i += 0.2){
        double sinx = Math.sin(i);
        series1.add(i, sinx);
    }


    final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    dataset.addSeries(series1);
```